# Rails 3.0.7: Mail is not a module - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

After setting up some Mailer-classes, I got this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.0.7/lib/action_mailer/tmail_compat.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': Mail is not a module (TypeError)
```

I have no idea what might be meant, do you have an idea?

I just created some mailers with `rails g mailer my_mailer` and after this, the error came up.

Please help.

Yours

Joern

Comment: How about adding some more of the stacktrace? This is too less context, so we would have to guess :-) And it would help if you would provide how you set up the mailer classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you define a class called `Mail` accidentally? This is a reserved class in Rails, as the `actionmailer` gem that comes with Rails depends on the `Mail` gem. You will have to choose another name.

Comment: I just created some mailers with `rails g mailer my_mailer` and after this, the error came up / to answer your question, I will have to look for it, but I'm quite sure I haven't created a `Mail` class or module

Comment: pardon, you're absolutey right, I have created a model called Mail... I should have find a solution for it on my own, but sometimes, the easiest the solutions are those, which are hardest to find ;)